# How to perform null check for NSArray element?

Tags: iphone, nsarray

I am developing an application in which i want to display array values

but if by any chance array value is null then how to check it as i do not

want to print values which are null because it is showing (null) as the value.

Even if have preformed [NSNULL null] but it does not seems to work..

Kindly help,

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Try the code bellow:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", [NSNull null], @"three", nil];
for (id obj in array) {
    if (obj != [NSNull null]) {
        NSLog(@"obj = %@", obj);
    }
}
```

I get:

2012-09-25 15:50:48.182 Test[4996:11303] obj = one

2012-09-25 15:50:48.184 Test[4996:11303] obj = three

Comment: this is correct but when i try to print array it shows
(
    one,
    "<null>",
    three
)
but when i try to print my arr ,it shows
(
    "Buss. No.",
    "(null)"
)
both array shows null value but with a different style that is why i am  not able to check my array's null value.
So, how to check this,kindly share...

Comment: Why there is a "(null)"? What you have inserted to that array?